# finding corresponding value for minimal number - r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame, where I would like to get the corresponding values the min value.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                       c(180,170,180,190,160,170,170,180),
                       c(80,75,76,81,67,65,66,70), 
                       c(5,6,7,8,9,5,6,7)
                 ))

df_stat <- setDT(df)[, list(
             min = min(X2)
            ), by = X1]
```

The outcome should be looking like

```
df_stat <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,2),
                            c(170,160),
                            c(75,67),
                            c(6,9)
                    ))
```

I have tried with which.min and others but they did not provide the right result.
Thanks in advance.
Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.SD` on your original data

```
setDT(df)
df[, .SD[which.min(X2)], by = X1]
#    X1  X2 X3 X4
# 1:  1 170 75  6
# 2:  2 160 67  9
```

---

Or you could sort by `X1` and `X2` and select unique `X1`

```
unique(setorder(df, X1, X2), by = "X1")
#    X1  X2 X3 X4
# 1:  1 170 75  6
# 2:  2 160 67  9
```

---

Or create an index using `.I` and then subset by it

```
indx <- df[, .I[which.min(X2)], by = X1]$V1
df[indx]
#    X1  X2 X3 X4
# 1:  1 170 75  6
# 2:  2 160 67  9
```